# Unaable to create tables after migrating the models from Django models.py

Tags: python, mysql, django

I created a user from `django.contrib.auth.models import User`
and I managed to migrate it to MySQL database using

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

but when I tried to add new tables in my app model.py when I make migrations it says that

> "No changes detected"

and when I use :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I receive this message which  includes the user tables but none of the models i created

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, api, auth,
>   authtoken, contenttypes, sessions Running migrations:   No migrations
>   to apply.

**My model code :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (
    (None, "indéterminé"),
    (True, "actif"),
    (False, "non actif")
)


class Departement(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nom = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    fk_transfo = models.ForeignKey(Transfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

class PointMesure (models.Model) :
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nom = models.TextField(max_length=64)
    etat = models.NullBooleanField(choices = CHOICES)
    nbHeursCons = models.FloatField()
    fk_departement = models.ForeignKey(Departement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

class Mesure (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    t = models.FloatField()
    i1inst = models.FloatField()
    i2inst = models.FloatField()
    i3inst = models.FloatField()
    i4inst = models.FloatField()
    u1inst = models.FloatField()
    u2inst = models.FloatField()
    u3inst = models.FloatField()
    p1 = models.FloatField()
    p2 = models.FloatField()
    p3 = models.FloatField()
    fk_PointMesure = models.ForeignKey(PointMesure, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __int__(self):
        return self.id

class ValCle (models.Model) :
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    i1 = models.FloatField()
    i2 = models.FloatField()
    i3 = models.FloatField()
    i4 = models.FloatField()
    u1 = models.FloatField()
    u2 = models.FloatField()
    u3 = models.FloatField()
    t = models.FloatField()
    phi1 = models.FloatField()
    phi2 = models.FloatField()
    phi3 = models.FloatField()
    fk_PointMesure = models.ForeignKey(PointMesure, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.t



class Machine(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.TextField(max_length=64)
    dateDernierMaintenance = models.DateField()
    dateInstallation = models.DateField()
    nbHeureSaisie = models.FloatField()
    consoKWH = models.FloatField()
    FK_pointMesure = models.ForeignKey(PointMesure, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    FK_departement = models.ForeignKey(Departement,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

Comment: have you added your apps to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in your Django settings?

Comment: Yes i already added it

Comment: Is your app name `api`? And if so, is the models.py file inside the `api` directory?

Comment: yes the app name is api and yes the models.py is inside the app

Comment: What does the `migrations` folder in your `api` project contains?

Comment: is there a `migrations` directory inside `api`? If yes, can you show us the file `0001_initial.py` file?

Comment: Also, using a MySQL visualiser, please show us the contents of the `django_migrations` table (columns `app` and `name`). Or the output of `SELECT app, name FROM django_migrations;`